# Should I edit my answer even if it makes my answer look like a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, comments

My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45507030/4052384) was posted at the same time as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45507015/4052384). According to another user, my answer wasn't a duplicate of his due to the fact the answers were posted practically the same time:

> This shouldn't be down voted as it is valid and was answered when Simon did.

So me and the other user were fine about our answers being pretty much the same until the OP of the other answer added this comment under my answer:

> I've also updated my answer due to comment from Chris_Rands; therefore, they are also two different answers as well now.

Chris_Rands' comment was that `.format()` was not necessary and thus should be removed. Though that comment was under another answer, I still think that it was both applicable to my answer and made my answer more correct.

But this causes this dilemma. If I edit my answer to remove `.format()` (in which I did about 30 min later) to make my answer better, it would seem I am trying to copy another answer. But if I don't, my answer wouldn't be the best, or at least as accurate as it can be. So should I edit my answer to improve its quality even if it makes my answer *look* like a duplicate of another?

Comment: Reason for removing/merging duplicates is to prevent having exactly same stuff multiple times which is exactly what makes se different compared to discussion forums where they lock old threads and ask for duplicated content. This is what makes those sites so bad for looking up good quality answers (not impossible but also not designed for that). Also older questio/answer could be closed as duplicate, it is not always about who fastest as here we should focus more on quality than timestamps. I would only recommend editing for better content. It is duplicate if it does not add anything

Comment: I would only recommend editing for better content. It is duplicate if it does not add anything and it should not be about who's fastest as on se we should focus more on quality than timestamps. Reason for removing/merging duplicates is to prevent having exactly same content here and there. That's what makes se different compared to discussion forums where they lock old threads and ask for duplicated content. This is what makes those sites so bad for looking up good quality answers (not impossible but also not designed for that). Older questions/answers might be removed as duplicate.

Comment: @SampoSarrala Speed is an issue I mention only because it helps prove that my answer is not a dupe of the other. If my answer was posted about 2 minutes after the previous answer, my answer would be a duplicate. I understand quality over speed, but speed here is only important in dupe or not dupe

Comment: The problem here is whether I should make the edit even if my answer would then look like a duplicate even though it's not.